# Agregar Layouts programaticamente en Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Buenas, necesito saber como crear Layouts programaticamente en ANDROID, como TextViews, RadioButtons, etc. O sea, con codigo Java.

Comment: Victor un Layout no es una vista de tipo TextView, RadioButton, etc.. Trata de especificar más tu pregunta, tal vez agregando un ejemplo, saludos!

Comment: Un Layout no es un TextView, pero un TextView si es un layout. Me refiero a agregar componentes como el TextView con codigo Java.

Comment: ok Victor, he agregado una respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda , todos los programadores que ayudan a los que recien estamos comenzamos nos sirve un monton este tipo de comentarios saludos!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de como agregar vistas y layout programaticamente a tu actividad. Se crea un contenedor, se crean las vistas a agregar al contenedor (`ImageView`, `TextView`), al final el contenedor es agregado a la vista principal.

```
    //Crea contenedor
    LinearLayout contenedor = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    contenedor.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contenedor.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    contenedor.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //Crea ImageView y TextView
    ImageView miImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    TextView miTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    //Agrega propiedades al TextView.
    miTextView.setText("mi TextView");
    miTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //Agrega imagen al ImageView.
    miImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    //Agrega vistas al contenedor.
    contenedor.addView(miTextView);
    contenedor.addView(miImageView);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1500, Gravity.CENTER);
    //Agrega contenedor con botones.
    addContentView(contenedor, params);
```

Al final tendrías esto como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dale, gracias, estaré probando.

Answer (score 0):

pues soy nuevo y yo lo he realizado así:
**Distribuidor en Malla**
Para usar el distribuidor en malla, se debe indicar en su constructor el número de filas y de columnas que va a tener. 4 filas y 3 columnas.
Eje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
setLayout( new GridLayout(4,3));
```

**Estos son otros que he aprendido pero el de `RadioButtons` no se como es.**

setText(etiqueta): permite cambiar el texto de la etiqueta

setForeground(color): permite cambiar el color.

Las zonas de texto (JTextField) , ingresar datos y obtener información.

getText(): retorna una cadena de caracteres de la caja de texto

setText(texto): presenta en la zona de texto la cadena que se pasa como parámetro.

setEditable(editable): indica si el contenedor puede ser modificado por el usuario.

setForeground(color): define el color de los caracteres.

setBackround(color): define el color del fondo.

*Ejemplos:*

```
Public class PanelVehiculo extends JPanel
{
Private JTextField txtMarca;
Private JTextField txtLinea;
Private JTextField txtModelo;
Private JTextField txtValor;
Private JLabel labMarca;
Private JLabel labLinea;
Private JLabel labModelo;
Private JLabel labValor;

Public PanelVehiculo()
{
labMarca = new  JLabel(“Marca”);
labLinea = new  JLabel(“Linea”);
labModelo = new JLabel(“Modelo”);
labValor = new JLabel(“Valor”);
txtMarca = new JTextField();
txtLinea = new JTextField();
txtModelo = new JTextField();
txtValor= new JTextField(“ $ 0”);
txtValor.setEditable( false );
txtValor.setForeground( Color.BLUE);
txtValor.setBackground( Color.WHITE);

add( labMarca );
add( txtMarca );
add(labLinea );
add( txtLinea );
add(labModelo);
add(txtModel);
add(labValor);
add(txtvalor);
}
}
```

VALIDACIÓN Y FORMATEO DE CAMPOS

```
Try {
     String strModelo = txtModelo.getText();
     Int nModelo = Integer.parseInt( strModelo );
}
Catch(Exception e) {
       txtModelo.setText(“ ”);
       //aqui van las instrucciones para enviar un mensaje al usuario
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

links de ayuda: [Interfaz de usuario android](http://www.aprendeandroid.com/l4/interface3.htm)

Comment: Gracias, deja leo la fuente, parece útil.

Comment: Juanzu el ejemplo que pones no tiene que ver con Android es de JavaFX :0!!!